# How to integrate google place finder in UitextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

im building an app in IOS, it has a `UITextView` where the user enters something like his address, but no the entire, Google should predict and complete the address, I already have a key from Google, pls help me with the implementation of this, i cant understand how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the google places Autocomplete Requests to a UITextField in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005494/how-to-set-the-google-places-autocomplete-requests-to-a-uitextfield-in-ios)

Comment: Or you can also use this https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have to get updated text from `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` delegate method. Then search best matched location using google map SDK.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
     [self searchLocationWithText:textView.text];
}

- (void)searchLocationWithText:(NSString *)searchText
{
     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%@&key=%@", searchText, kGoogleSDKBrowserKey];
     NSURL *googleRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
     // Retrieve the results of the URL.
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleRequestURL];
          NSError *error = nil;
          NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

          if ([[json objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"])  {
              NSArray *locations = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
              NSDictionary *place = [locations firstObject];
              NSString *locationName = [place objectForKey:@"name"];
              // Set location name to your textView
              textView.text = locationName;
          }
     });
}
```

Here kGoogleSDKBrowserKey is your registered API key. Also refer [how to register for Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/#Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement `UITextFieldDelegate`,
in your `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` method you should have something like that :

```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    // your code to send the search string to google place API  
    return YES;
}
```

When your search request to google places API is complete don't forget to reload the data of your UITableView using : `[yourTable reloadData]`

Hope this helps.

Cheers.